# Using R to solve equations

Tags: r, numerical-methods

How might I solve for the roots of an equation of the following form numerically in R:

```
f(r)=r*c+1-B*c-exp(-M(B-r))
```

Where M, B and c are known constants.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the rootSolve package? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/rootSolve.pdf

Comment: This really isn't the sort of thing that R is inherently good at.  A symbolic package like Maxima is better suited for symbolic work and will be less fuss about it.

Comment: What do you mean by "none constants"? Your function f only has one parameter, if you want to find r such that f(r)=0 then the other things will have to be constants.

Comment: @Dinre  Assuming the OP understands what "numerically" means, he isn't looking for `yacas` or `macsyma` -- better to send him to package `BB`

Comment: "none" is probably "known"

Comment: @Stijn The root solve package worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: @Spacedman Yes that should have read known rather than none. Apologies.

Comment: okay, thought you meant 'non-constants'! Will edit...

Comment: R provides uniroot for such equations. Besides rootSolve, BB there is also nleqslv.

Answer (score 4):

Since R can not do this functionality you might want to use a superset package like Sage.  Sage includes R and many other packages and can do what you want using a webbrowser interface.  The site is http://www.sagemath.org/

Examples are located at: http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/symbolic/relation.html

You can try stuff like the following at: http://www.sagenb.org/

```
var('r', 'c', 'B', 'M')
f = r*c+1-B*c-exp(-M(B-r))
print solve(f, r)
```

The results of this is:

r == (B*c + e^(-B + r) - 1)/c

Comment: The link above is broken but this one works: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/