# solve complex number equation in R

Tags: r

I am getting an equation with this form

```
exp(az) = 1 + cz
```

which I wanna solve for z,

where c is a complex number, so expectedly z is complex also. 
I cannot figure out how to solve an equation involving complex number in R.

I hope anybody can help me

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646542/using-r-to-solve-equations - this is not really R's strength.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha can get a solution in terms of the *Lambert W* function (which it calls the `ProductLog` function):

[image]

The `emdbook` package (among others) has an implementation of the Lambert W function. (In order to make this work I had to fix a bug, so you can't use the CRAN implementation.  Instead, install the latest version from Github: `library(devtools); install_github("bbolker/emdbook")` ...

```
library(emdbook)
sfun <- function(a,c) {
    w <- lambertW(-a/c*exp(-a/c))
    -(c*w+a)/(a*c)
}
```

Example

```
a <- 2+1i; c <- 1+1i
(z <- sfun(a,c))
## [1] -0.1686391-0.2337278i
```

Check answer:

```
(exp(a*z)-(1+c*z))
## [1] 0+5.551115e-17i
```

This is zero to within expected numeric tolerance ...

Comment: Thx a lot Ben; really a good solution. I am tested your solution, and all OK with the procedure to find a root z. However, I did not obtain the derivation of (the expressions in) these 2 lines: `w <- lambertW(-a/c*exp(-a/c))  -(c*w+a)/(a*c)`. Could you please add this derivation to the solution? Also, I applied the above procedure, and I got `> (z <- sfun(a,c))
[1] -0.224767+0.4937739i   > (exp(a*z)-(1+c*z))    [1] 5.55112e-17+1.665335e-16i`. This is also within tolerance. Is a set.seed() needed to get exactly the same result?

Comment: Now, I obtained the derivation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1  !  It would be nicer if I add it above as well.

Comment: roundoff error may vary across platforms (operating system, compiler, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

The intermediate step in Ben Bolker's solution:

[image]